# Client/Server communication using ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, client-server

I have some questions  about the client/server communication.
The way I understand it, it goes like this :

The client sends a page request

The server responds with a html page

Now, when the client sends a postBack, which files are sent ? Is it the whole html document ? My guess is that it only sends the viewState values.

When the server answers to a postBack, does it send the whole page again ?

Comment: Please refer this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/121096/Web-Server-and-ASP-NET-Application-Life-Cycle-in-D

Comment: "Please explain me HTTP and ASP.NET's Page Lifecycle" is a tad too broad. Educate yourself, see for example @Sain's link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How are parameters sent in an HTTP POST request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request)

Comment: Well I just wanted a simple answer, like yes or no?
Does the server send the whole page after a postBack? Is that too hard to answer? Thank you anyway...

Comment: Server sends html of whole page after a postback.